# Calculating the percentage of different types of customer feedback in each quarter

Tags: sql, scripting, dml

The problem statement is: I have a table (`order_t`) which has customer feedback (one column) and quarter number (as another column).

Using a CTE, I need to calculate the percentage of number of customer feedback in each category as well as the total number of customer feedback in each quarter.

After this happens, I need the percentage of different types of customer feedback (like good, bad, ok, very good, very bad) but using CTE.

How can I solve this statement?

I try to solve customer feedback as

```
WITH total_feedback AS
(
    SELECT *
        COUNT(CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK), QUARTER NUMBER 
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY 
        2 
)
```

But I'm unable to calculate the first half portion, i.e. percentage of different types of customer feedback in each quarter using CTE.

How can I do that?

[Find the file of the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fb_lrSLBMkvAlHX61UxQUSSt34cPxeoQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, and I'll keep the example as close to the code you provided as possible, is the following - using 2 CTE's:

```
WITH total_feedback AS (
    SELECT COUNT(CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK) AS total_feedback, QUARTER_NUMBER
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY 2
),

category_feedback AS (
    SELECT COUNT(CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK) AS feedback_count, CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK, QUARTER_NUMBER
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY 2, 3
)

SELECT
    category_feedback.CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK,
    category_feedback.QUARTER_NUMBER,
    (feedback_count / total_feedback.total_feedback) * 100 AS feedback_percentage
FROM category_feedback
INNER JOIN total_feedback
    ON category_feedback.QUARTER_NUMBER = total_feedback.QUARTER_NUMBER
```